# how to post "submit" with php cUrl

Tags: php, arrays, post, curl, submit

I am trying to curl post with php
The page I am trying to submit has codes like this

```
<input name="fname" type="hidden" value="show">
<input name="method" type="submit" value="Continue">
```

I am trying to simulate this "sumbit"(continue) button and follow redirection with php

```
$post= array("method=>Continue")

$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $string);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
 $h = curl_exec($ch);
echo $h;
```

What should I have in the $post= array(?).
I have tried  $post= array(name => method). Not working..any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option to the array itself:

```
$post = array(
    "method" => "Continue",
    "fname" => "show"
);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the html has  <input name="fname" type="hidden" value="show">

Comment: @AbulHasnat add that name & value to the array, updated answer.